# Why are the Mimics so named?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

The baddies in Edge of Tomorrow are black, amorphous tentacled creatures called Mimics. The problem is, as best as I can remember, they never actually mimic anything. And they certainly don't look like they're mimicking anything found on Earth. So who gave them that name, and why?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

They were called mimics because they were capable of mimicking human military behavior extremely quickly.  This happened to be a result of the Omega's time traveling capabilities, but the humans in the movie had no idea about that.  All they knew was that they would attack one way, and the aliens immediately knew how to counter it or do it themselves.

> Sky News Anchor: They appear to mimic and even anticipate our
>   actions...

Comment: Beofett's answer may be technically correct, but I like this answer because it comes from within the same canon source itself.

Comment: The canon source is All You Need is Kill. This movie is an adaptation...not the canon source.

Comment: @Thaddeus Although it is an adaptation, the question is about that adaptation, not the original source.  Evidenced in other areas (specifically thinking on TWD), the original source and the adaptation often have differences.  I think when this happens, answers from the original source are only better if there is no answer from the questioned source.  This is especially true when talking about movies made from books.  WWZ is an excellent example as well.

Comment: I agree with Thaddeus about *All You Need is Kill* being "true" canon, since there are several adaptations, and *Edge of Tomorrow* contains the least detail (as is typical with movies). However, I upvoted this answer because I agree answering with sources from the version being asked about is as good as canon in most cases. I obviously don't think my answer is wrong for going more into the canon explanation, but this is definitely a good answer.

Comment: No, a piece of art A is not "true canon" for separate piece of art B, even when B was inspired by or is an adaptation of A. The question is about the movie, so the answer should be about the movie.

Comment: The OP did not specify "only movie sources". It is widely accepted here that information from alternate sources is acceptable unless specifically addressed by the OP (respecting potential spoilers, of course). You can make that distinction in your questions, but making declarations like this on other people's guidance is misguided.

Comment: @Beofett I was not assuming he wanted "only movie sources", but since that is what he tagged (as the book does have its own tag) it is safe to assume that is what he/she is interested in.  Either way, I was merely disputing the fact that the book is more canon than the movie when someone is asking about the movie.

Comment: @DaveJohnson I don't disagree with you.  My prior comment was intended for Lightness Races in Orbit, who claims "the answer should be about the movie", and who also commented on my answer claiming it was irrelevant. I agree that the OP clearly is interested in the movie, but disagree with Lightness' assumption that the OP implicitly has **no** interest in the book or manga. Not everyone watching a movie remake is even aware that it is based upon something else. As I mentioned before, I think your answer is good, and it received a +1 from me.

Answer (score 50):

In Hiroshi Sakurazaka's *All You Need is Kill*, the novel upon which the movie was based, the Mimics are alien organisms (nanobots?) sent to "terraform" the earth to make it habitable for an alien race from a nearby star system.

Iirc, the "mimics" invaded native life (starfish) in order to co-opt their biology into a platform upon which they could build a bio-weapon, and were designed to adapt to their surroundings in order to accomplish their mission (including their ability to "loop back time" in order to anticipate dangers and other obstacles).  They mimicked terran biology in order to adapt to the earth's environment, so that they could evolve and reproduce enough to begin transforming the earth into an environment more hospitable to their creators.

This ability to adapt is one reason they are called mimics.

It also appears that this may be a translation issue.

According to an answer I found on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-Japanese-word-Gitai-%E3%82%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4), the original Japanese can be translated as "Gitai":

> In that katakana form (ギタイ) it doesn't mean anything. It's just a name. But, it can be written in kanji as 擬態 (mimesis, mimicry, camouflage) or 義体 (artificial body, cyborg).

Comment: Japanese names always get these slight translation errors or differences, ive read manga that were translated by 10 different people throughout the series, and peoples names changed 10 different times lol.

Comment: The novel is excellent, incidentally.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an example of that @Himarm if you had a link handy??

Comment: @Daft i dont have any handy but one i easily remember is names from dragon ball, in the english dubs, mercenary tao is a villian goku fights, in the subs, hes called tao pia pia, or general toa pia. typically when you see a name like that, tao pia pia, it doesnt have an english translation. so when the dubs were being made they decided to americanize the name and made it mercenary tao. but different english manga translations have like 6 different names for him as well, as each translator took some liberties with his name since it doesnt actually translate.

Comment: @Himarm ah I see. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting, but none of it is relevant to the canon of the film.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by "none", you're including the part about how they adapt and looping back in time? My answer addresses information from the movie as well as the book. It only lacks a direct quote. Also note the OP did not say " I'm only interested in sources from within the movie", therefore your assumption that the movie is the only valid canon is seemingly without basis.

Comment: @Beofett: Yes, I'm including that. You can't take similarities between the book and movie and use that to make claims about _other_ aspects of the movie that were, in fact, only in the book. By default, when you ask for information on piece of art B, _that is the canon in question_. If the OP wanted to allow answers for _both distinct pieces of art_ then he would have said so. I think you have your defaults backwards. =)

Comment: Again, you are extending *your personal opinion*, and assuming it is site convention, when the vast majority disagrees with you.